# HTTP header set with PHP is still set even when serving static file

Tags: wordpress, caching, http-headers, apache2.4

Okay, this is the scenario:

I use Wordpress which sets x-pingback header.
I used cache mechanism, which always using mod_rewrite serves the static html file. Just trust me the cache works the way I described.

How come I still see x-pingback header being set?! WP is putting that header with PHP... but now the visitors never hit PHP but instead they are served a static html file.

What am I missing here?!

Comment: How do you know mod_rewrite doesn't hit Wordpress? I think it's pretty obvious that when PHP code adds that header and you see that header, the request went through PHP.

Comment: Well this is why I'm asking the question, you make sense. If in the apache settings I have written a rule to serve www.example.com/post65 -> var/www/cache/post65.html it shouldn't hit the WP and it shouldn't show the header, correct?

Comment: I didn't know it was possible to rewrite beyond the document root. Are you sure that request isn't going to end up at `http://your-wordpress/var/www/cache/post56.html`, where Wordpress will look up the post based on the slug? Can you show the relevant mod_rewrite rules you have?

Comment: Thank you, I solved it by myself... a bit stupid but I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thansk @CodeCaster for thinking with me.

Okay, the problem was my index/home page was not cached. On purpose!
I knew this page will set the header, but what I didn't know that pages that are being served as static carried that header with it!

I opened incognito window and checked the headers of a post - it was gone. When I navigated to home, there was header, as expected. I refreshed the the post now again and boom - the header was there!